# Ruby sha512 password retrieval in php

Tags: php, ruby, hash, passwords, sha512

(Updated due to some confusion over my question) We use this method to generate a digested_password, which is saved to our database for later lookup. When we authenticate a user to our application, this method is again ran against their input and if the digested_password output matches the digested_password we saved in the database we authenticate them.  I need to reproduce this function in PHP for another application that shares the database.

```
def self.hash_password( password, salt )
  salted_password = password.insert 4, salt
  digested_password = Digest::SHA512.hexdigest("#{salted_password}")
  return digested_password
end
```

I really have no experience with Ruby so please forgive my lack of understanding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can't "retrieve" a password from a one-way hash like SHA-512, the closest we can get is being able to generate the same hash from the same password and salt.  Let's look at the Ruby code:

```
def self.hash_password( password, salt )
  salted_password = password.insert 4, salt
  digested_password = Digest::SHA512.hexdigest("#{salted_password}")
  return digested_password
end
```

The only thing a bit "weird" here is the call to the [`.insert` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001130) on the password string.  It's basically splicing the salt right into the password, starting at the fourth character index.  Normally salts are simply concatenated with the password.

We can replicate this using [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
function hash_password($password, $salt) {
    $salted_password = substr($password, 0, 4) . $salt . substr($password, 4);
    return hash('sha512', $salted_password);
}
```

I'm using the now-default [hash extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) here, as it's pretty much the most reliable way to generate a SHA-512 hash.

Using this code, you should be able to generate identical hashes for a given identical password and salt combination.  I'm not sure what the behavior would be when the password is less than five characters long.

---

Yup, looks like it should work:

```
[charles@lobotomy ~]$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'digest/sha2'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> def hash_password( password, salt )
irb(main):003:1>   salted_password = password.insert 4, salt
irb(main):004:1>   digested_password = Digest::SHA512.hexdigest("#{salted_password}")
irb(main):005:1>   return digested_password
irb(main):006:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):007:0* puts hash_password('password', 'salt')
92d3efdbf51d199b0930c427b77dc8d5cf41ac58b6fab5f89cc3f32d719a8f6ffcdff6211bdd0565a6e7b09925839e5dcce1fa5abf65eca87c6a883ab0b510b9
=> nil
irb(main):018:0> exit
[charles@lobotomy ~]$ 
[charles@lobotomy ~]$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > function hash_password($password, $salt) {
php {     $salted_password = substr($password, 0, 4) . $salt . substr($password, 4);
php {     return hash('sha512', $salted_password);
php { }
php > echo hash_password('password', 'salt');
92d3efdbf51d199b0930c427b77dc8d5cf41ac58b6fab5f89cc3f32d719a8f6ffcdff6211bdd0565a6e7b09925839e5dcce1fa5abf65eca87c6a883ab0b510b9
php >
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't very clear in my question, but we are actually storing the digested_password and their salt in the database.  When a user logs into the system this function is run against the user input and the salt, and if the crypted password in the database matches the digest_password from this method we authenticate them.  I simply need a PHP equivalent for another application that shares this database.  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @somecallmemike, in that case, the function I whipped up here *should* do the job.

Comment: Ruby would trigger an error if the string was too short. So it really probably doesn't matter what the PHP version does on short strings, since this is for authentication.

Comment: @konforce, that's good to know -- PHP's behavior here is simply to treat the out-of-range substring as empty and not complain about being told to do insane things.  Way to go, PHP!

Answer (score 2):

```
function hash_password($password, $salt)
{
  $salted_password = substr_replace($password, $salt, 4, 0);
  $digested_password = hash('sha512', $salted_password);
  return $digested_password;
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Didn't see your reply until I answered the question.  This is a much better implementation, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[SHA512](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) is a [**one way** hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function), meaning that you can't easily get the input for any given output.

It is possible, but very expensive, to build a [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table). Because this is a salted hash, it's even more difficult

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I didn't quite understand the insert method in Ruby, and it turns out the salt is being inserted into the password at the fourth character.  Here is the PHP equivalent:

```
$password_input = "derpaderp";
$password_salt = "aderp";
$arg=substr_replace($password_input, $password_salt, 4, 0);
$pass = hash('sha512', $arg);
if ( $digested_password_from_database == $pass ){ echo "success!"; }
```

Thanks for your replies folks.